# Matrix group,inverse elements.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If i have a specific matrix group with matrices $A,B,C,D$ where $Α$ is the identity element and also $BD=A$,$DB=A,C^2=A,A^2=A$. That means that $C$ and $A$ are inverse elements of their selfs.

Does this creates problems to it's requirements for being a group?

Comment: That's fine. Your matrix group is cyclic of order 4.There even exist groups of very large or even infinite orders where every element is self-inverse.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no problem.  It's perfectly possible to have elements of a group that are their own inverses.  For instance, the complex numbers $A=1$, $B=i$, $C=-1$, and $D=-i$ satisfy all the equations you've written and form a group (even a group of matrices, if you consider them as $1\times 1$ matrices).

Comment: Or even $2\times 2$ matrices if you consider the usual matrix representation.

Answer (score 0):

They can be:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad C=\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad D=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$